# shiny R: how to sort dataframe reactively using gvisTable

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am building a web app that takes input values from users, create a dataframe with it, and eventually show it using gvisTable. However, I am struggling with sorting the dataframe by score column dynamically.

Here is what I have in the server.R file:

```
values<- reactiveValues() 
  values$df<- data.frame()

  observeEvent(input$click_counter, {
    name<- input$name
    gender<- input$gender
    college<- input$college
    team<- input$team
    score<- as.numeric(input$score)
    rank<- 0

    new_row<- data.frame(rank,name,college,gender,team,score)

    values$df<- rbind(values$df, new_row)
    values$df<- values$df[order(values$df$score,decreasing=TRUE),]
    values$df$rank<- 1:nrow(values$df)
  })

dff1 <- data.frame()
  output$summa2 <- renderGvis({
    for (team_name in unique(values$df$team)){
      rank <- 0
      team <- team_name
      score <- format(mean(values$df[values$df$team==team_name,]$score), digits=4)

      new_row<- data.frame(rank, team, score)

      dff1 <<- rbind(dff1, new_row)
      dff1 <<- dff1[order(dff1$score,decreasing=FALSE),]
      dff1$rank <<- 1:nrow(dff1)
    }
    return(gvisTable(dff1))
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't reproducible, but I'll guess you need to add the `sortColumn` option in `gvisTable`.

Like this:

```
return(gvisTable(dff1, options=list(sortColumn='COLUMN_NUMBER'))
```

Just replace the 'COLUMN_NUMBER' for the desired column.